# Why my SwiftUI component has a circle-backslash?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget

I wanna make an iOS 14 widget which has a scrollview display some `Text()`. But when adding the `SliderTitle()` it's has a red circle-backslash inside like this:

[image]
[image]
What's wrong with my code? And why it's doesn't show full string even I set the `lineLimit` to nil

Comment: You used some not allowed view. Add your code as code, not screenshot.

Comment: Can you add scrollviews in widgets? I thought widgets were static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't use `ScrollView` in Widgets (you're not allowed to scroll anyway).

Widget views are *static* and they don't allow much interaction (with the exception of `Link`).

You need to replace the `ScrollView` with another container, eg. a `HStack`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can use it because of the Smart Stack. I wanna make a widget which can swipe to change its content like it.

Comment: @Bad_Developer The Smart Stack allows swiping between Widgets, you can't swipe on the contents of a specific Widget.

Comment: So. How to make a smart stack? Apple doesn't mention it in their videos. Can we really do it?

Comment: @Bad_Developer You can drag one Widget on top of another - just like you're creating app folders.